# Laravel yield Content not showing

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am new in laravel, and I am trying to create layout, but my `@yield` is not working when I view in browser its shows everything, but it doesn't show any thing from `dashboard.blade.php`

**dashboard.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.main')
    @section('content')
  <div class="page-title">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>
@endsection
```

**main.blade.php**

```
@include('includes.header')
<!-- page content -->
<div class="right_col" role="main">
  <div class="">
    @yield('content')
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /page content -->
```

**includes/header.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- My CSS Links -->
  </head>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/dashboard','DashboardController@index');
```

**DashboardController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DashboardController extends Controller{

  public function index(){
    return view('admin.layouts');
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: `return view('admin.layouts');`, Are you sure about the page being returned here? Shouldn't it be `something.dashboard`?

Comment: Hello @ImeshaSudasingha its inside admin folder so when i add `return view('admin.dashboard');` its not working its says View [layouts.main] not found. (View: ..\resources\views\admin\dashboard.blade.php)

Comment: Can you put your directory structure here? Your views should be in `resources/views` directory. In that directory there should be a file `admin/layouts.blade.php`

Comment: My directory structure look like this `resources/views/admin/layouts/main.blade.php`

Comment: So? That is the error. `@extends('layouts.main')` should be `@extends('admin.layouts.main')`. Directories should be named relative to `views` directory

Comment: Thank you bro now its work :)